# using sequence in namedparameterJDBCTemplate for insertion into two tables

Tags: java

how to use sequence in namedparameterJDBCTemplate for insertion into two tables ?
    Database- orcale
    springjdbcnamedparametertemplate .

my Dao is looking like this

```
@Override
    public void insert(Message message) {
        String SQL = "INSERT into mssg (mssg_id, mssg_text, mssg_channel)"
                + " values (mssg_sequence.nextval,:mssg_text,:mssg_channel)";

        String SQLMessage_app = "INSERT into message_app(mssg_app_type,mssg_id)"
                + "values(:mssg_app_type,mssg_sequence.currval)";
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(SQL,
                new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(message));
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(SQLMessage_app,
                new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(message));
    }
```

oracle  tables are these

This is the first  table

```
create table mssg (
mssg_id number(10) NOT NULL,
mssg_text varchar2(25)NOT NULL,
mssg_channel varchar(25)NOT NULL,
constraint pk_mssg_id PRIMARY KEY(mssg_id)
);

Create sequence mssg_sequence
start with 1
increment by 1
minvalue 1
maxvalue 100000;
```

This is the second table

```
CREATE TABLE MESSAGE_APP( 
mssg_app_type VARCHAR2(25),
mssg_id NUMBER(10),
CONSTRAINT fk_mssg
    FOREIGN KEY(mssg_id)
    REFERENCES mssg(mssg_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE);
COMMIT;
```

iam getting this error :

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT
>   into
>   message_app(mssg_app_type,mssg_id)values(?,mssg_sequence.currval)];
>   SQL state [72000]; error code [8002]; ORA-08002: sequence
>   MSSG_SEQUENCE.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session ; nested
>   exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08002: sequence
>   MSSG_SEQUENCE.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session

can anybody help me to insert data into two tables by using sequence???

Thanks in advance :)